# Is there a convention for asking questions about finance in a specific country?

Tags: discussion

I am from the UK, but a lot of the questions on the site are from the US. Is there a convention for asking UK specific questions?

Comment: We have member from all over the globe, and even those in the US are happy to learn from the UK-centric questions.

Answer (score 6):

Yup.  Questions that might be localized to a country or region should start with the right **tag**.

Here are the top 5 country tags on the site, right now:

- [united-states](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) x 2216
- [canada](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada) x 406
- [united-kingdom](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) x 246
- [india](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) x 140
- [australia](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia)  x 72

n.b. Questions that *aren't* country-specific won't have a country tag, so you'll also find a lot of questions on the site that may be relevant to somebody in the U.K. but not tagged [united-kingdom](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom).